# pip install gitpython fails with python 3.x requirement

Tags: python-2.7, debian, raspbian, gitpython, debian-buster

When I try to install gitpython via pip normally under python 2.7, it fails telling me python 3.x is required.

This particular script/process has worked until this morning.

```
 $ sudo pip install gitpython
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting gitpython
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/gitpython/GitPython-2.1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
GitPython requires Python '>=3.0, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*' but the running Python is 2.7.16
```

I am running Python 2.7.16

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

When I check the current [documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#requirements) I see that Python 2.7 or newer is listed as a requirement.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the [documentation was lagging](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/897), and Python 2.7 support was dropped in [dac619e](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/commit/dac619e4917b0ad43d836a534633d68a871aecca).

Assuming other folks are procrastinating as I am in getting to Python 3, I've created [a fork of GitPython which is current with 2.1.12](https://github.com/lbussy/GitPython) and reverts only those changes which eliminated stated compatibility for Python 2.7.  My fork is expected to remain static with the 0.2.12a release and otherwise even with mainline [GitPython 2.1.12](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/releases/tag/2.1.12).

I've created a small batch file for folks who may want/need to automate the installation process of this fork:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gitpython() {
    local cwd repo pipList found
    pipList=$(pip list)
    found=$(grep -o "GitPython" <<< "$pipList" | wc -l)
    repo="https://github.com/lbussy/GitPython.git"
    if [ "$found" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo -e "\nDownloading and installing GitPython for Python 2.7."
        cwd=$(pwd)
        git clone "$repo" "$HOME/git-python" &>/dev/null || die "$@"
        cd "$HOME/git-python" || die "$@"
        eval "python setup.py install" &>/dev/null || die "$@"
        cd "$cwd" || die "$@"
        rm -fr "$HOME/git-python"
        echo -e "\nGitPython for Python 2.7 install complete."
    else
        echo -e "\nGitPython for Python 2.7 already installed."
    fi
}

function die
{
    local message=$1
    [ -z "$message" ] && message="Died"
    echo "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}: line ${BASH_LINENO[0]}: ${FUNCNAME[1]}: $message." >&2
    exit 1
}

main() {
    gitpython "$@"
}

main "$?" && exit 0
```

Installed in this manner, it is still able to be managed by pip going forward.